# Flutter firebase - can't catch exception thrown white trying to update a document with a map with an empty key

Tags: firebase, flutter, try-catch

While trying to update a document in Firestore with a map with an empty key (a bug in my code), I wasn't able to catch the exception, which resulted in an app crash.

Here's a sample code:

```
try {
Map<String, dynamic> crash = {"": 3}; // this is an empty key (bug)
await docRef.collection('collection').document('doc').updateData({"ABC": crash});
} catch (err) {
print(err);
}
```

The exception (quite reasonable):

```
*** Assertion failure in auto firebase::firestore::model::FieldPath::FromServerFormat(const absl::string_view)::(anonymous class)::operator()() const(), /project/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/model/field_path.cc:90
Lost connection to device.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid field path (s3SEDn5nhnWiqeZjpDmY.``). Paths must not be empty, begin with '.', end with '.', or contain '..' (expected !segment.empty())'
```

I don't see the error printed to the console, nor I get to a breakpoint set there.

My questions / issues:

1. Am I using the try catch block in a wrong way? Why isn't the catch statement working?
2. After the app crashes, trying to relaunch it fails, with the following error:

```
FileSystemException: Getting current working directory failed, path = '' (OS Error: Too many open files in system, errno = 23)
```

Only uninstalling and reinstalling the app works.
Any idea if this is normal? If not, what can I do about it?

Crashes both on iOS and Android,
Firestore plugin version cloud_firestore: ^0.12.7

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to catch exeptions on updateData with a map with no internet connection (emulator).

```
    await Firestore.instance.collection('collection').document(doc).updateDataa({"ABC": crash}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
```

This was the only way i could handle the timeout and return connection error!

Comment: It would be nice if you could add more clarification to the answer.